# Kivy not show console on windows without packaging

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, kivy

I want to run my python 3 kivy script on windows without the console window showing but .pyw prevents kivy running at all.

I very new to programming and packaging the script is beyond me. As I haven't understand a tenth of the docs for pyinstaller etc.

Is there any way to do this without packaging?